# changing the color of each items in ul tag

Tags: jquery

I am new in JQuery. I want to do this Job. If the user goes with the mouse over a text a *ul* shold be shown to the user and if the user select each of iems in this *ul* then the color of this *li* should be changed to red. I have written this code but if the user select a *li* the color of all lis are changed, how can I solve my problem, thanks?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div1').hover(function () {
            $('#ul1').css("display", "")
        },
            function () {
                $("#ul1").css("display", "none");
            });
        $('li').hover(function () {
            $('li').css("color", "red")
        }, function () {
            $('li').css('color', 'black');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to our website</h1>
<br />
<div id="div1"><p id="p1" style="font-size:large">Our products </p>
<br />
<ul style="display:none" id="ul1" >
<li>Milch</li>
<li>Schokolade</li>
<li>kuchen</li>
<li>Honig</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side: in this simple example, the hover color styling really should be done in CSS, rather than JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only CSS:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cRY7L/)

```
#ul1 {display:none;}
#div1:hover #ul1{display:block;}
#ul1 li:hover {color:red}
```

Otherwise:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xeE4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div1').hover(function () {
        $('#ul1').toggle()
    });
    $('#ul1 li').hover(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "red")
    }, function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
    });
});
```

Instead of using css() method, for styling you should use a class:

```
.red {color:red;}
```

Then your code could be just:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div1').hover(function () {
        $('#ul1').toggle()
    });
    $('#ul1 li').hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("red");
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xeE4/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)` to change color of hovered `li` only

```
 $('li').hover(function () {
      $(this).css("color", "red")
 }, function () {
      $(this).css('color', 'black');
 });
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9hE/